# Catch' block is unreachable but I included try

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm getting the following error:

```
'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
```

But my try is present, how can I include the error then?

```
AF.request(url).responseData(completionHandler: { data in
    do {
        if let apiJsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: data.data!){
            self.items = apiJsonData.data.items
        }
    } catch {
        print("Decoding failed -> ERROR:", error)
    }
}
```

If I include it in the header like: `data, error in` it throws an error:

```
Contextual closure type '(AFDataResponse<Data>) -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Data, AFError>) -> ()') expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body
```

How can I have the try catch correctly setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've used `try?`, not `try`.

`try?` turns the whole expression into `nil` if an error was thrown. It already handles the error on its own, so there's no more error for the `catch` block to catch. On the other hand, `try` doesn't do that. For more info, see the [Error handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) section of the Swift Guide.

If you want the error to be caught by the `catch` block, you should use `try`, and delete the `if` block.

```
AF.request(url).responseData(completionHandler: { data in
    do {
        let apiJsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: data.data!)
        self.items = apiJsonData.data.items
    } catch {
        print("Decoding failed -> ERROR:", error)
    }
}
```

Also note that you are assuming `data.data` is not nil here. This might not be the case if the network request fails. Better check for it:

```
AF.request(url).responseData(completionHandler: { data in
    do {
        guard let data = data.data else {
            print("Response Error:", data.error)
            return
        }
        let apiJsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: data.data!)
        self.items = apiJsonData.data.items
    } catch {
        print("Decoding failed -> ERROR:", error)
    }
}
```